# Unable to perform any kind of operation on MircoSD card

Tags: sd-card, gparted

I have a 8 GB SDcard that look like this in gparted:
[image: gparted]

My goal is to have a single 8 GB partition on the SDcard.

When I try to perform any operation (delete partition, create new partition, change format, etc) its successful but nothing changes.
[image: gparted delete all]

Gparted shows that all operations are successful:
[image: gparted all successful]

But when I click Close it will reload the device and show the same partition table as before.

I also ran "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M" which showed no error but the partitions are still there.

One more strange thing is that if mount one of the partitions (eg sdb1) add or delete any files, eject/unmount and remount. The changes are gone (no files added or removed). The same thing happens when I access the 1GB FAT32 partition on a Windows PC.

Is there any way the SDcard could be locked to prevent all those changes?
Is there a way to solve this or do i need a new SDcard?

Comment: "Is there any way the SDcard could be locked to prevent all those changes?" - Firmware could manage this.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you know of a way I can check that?

Answer (score 0):

Many SD cards have a write protect lock on the side.  Be sure that the lock is set so that writing to the SD card is permitted.

Comment: I'm using a micro Sdcard reader so there is no lock