# Remove formatting and partitions on a storage device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, formatting, storage

Under some circumstances, normal partitioning tools refuse do the requested work;
i.e. removing partitions, and deleting the partition table is troublesome...

How to get past this state? Please provide an OS-agnostic method!

Comment: There's probably 100's of articles, forum posts, blog posts and whatnot on this topic.

Comment: So, voting down was quick... please explain where the problem is. Searching for a similar answer turns up while writing this...

Comment: Links please, did not turn up as I wrote it.

Comment: There's zero effort in this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DiskPart won't let me delete a partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1291851/diskpart-wont-let-me-delete-a-partition)

Comment: Well, "maybe" there is windows stuff in the question. *sigh*

Comment: the proposed solution is a linux tool which you'd have discovered if you would have read a little further - *sigh*

Comment: I've read it; but a windows question is a poor find for a linux user. Tags: has no indication of linux "windows-10 partitioning powershell"

Comment: It's often wise, for self-answers aiming to become canonical, to let people know in the question - a bit of explanatory <sub> at the end. Some don't read far enough down before jumping on the dv/cv bandwagon. The question itself does look too broad & un-researched; the answer fixes that, but perhaps too late for some. I'd also mention OS in the question body - some don't read tags either.

Comment: Hmm... idéa - make this a bit more OS agnostic...

Comment: In Linux: [`wipefs -a`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/wipefs.8.html).

Comment: And yes, there are other methods... :-)

Comment: Almost funny, `wipefs -b` has a `dd` option to restore the backup ;-)

Comment: You are getting down votes because you've given an excessively broad query without any focus, you've got a question in the title (that's not where the question goes), and have added question marks in a few places that are not, grammatically, questions. Use the EDIT button and make this is a clear question with information specific enough to make it clear what you need.

Comment: The broad question DOES HAVE an answer, isn't that so? Now, edited to make it more on the point, with a single question mark as that seems to be important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: A disk, SD-card or USB-memory can be formatted with a single filesystem entry, without "partitioning"; this normally works, but some OS's have (or has had) trouble with understanding what it is.*

---

**OS -agnostic**; e.g. a method that does not rely on any OS of your installed OS and can be used for "operations" on all of the ones you HAVE installed.
*(Now; I'm not sure that is entirely true, but i believe it comes close)*

1. Have a look at https://releases.ubuntu.com/ and select one of the LTS releases; maybe best with the latest - unless it is very recent
   *(a very recent one may contain irks that has not yet been ironed out)*
2. Download that ISO
3. Prepare an "installation media" - e.g. a USB-stick with the ISO you downloaded.
4. Boot that installation media in "Try Ubuntu" -mode.
5. You now have an OS running that does not depend of your currently installed OS's in any way - you're free to do anything at will.

---

**BEWARE:**
  `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb` is written out below.
  **If *your*   /dev/sdb, and any of sdb1 to sdb*n*   contains data that is precious to you**;
  this will - without exception - remove all of it;
  it might even be hard to regain control of it with e.g. `Testdisk` (search for old disk content).
  *You MUST adapt the /dev/xxx to what you're attempting.*

---

**How to actually do it**

As can be expected from above this description is slanted for using **Ubuntu** Linux (20.04 specifically if that needs to be said);

Clearing formatting and partitioning can be done with the following "brute force" method...

After booting in "Try mode" you end up with a Ubuntu desktop...

To open a Terminal/Shell/Bash-prompt; hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> and hit <kbd>T</kbd>

Here

```
$ lsblk
```

... will print info about all known media, `lsblk -ape7` will show even more, excluding any loop devices *(which generally are uninteresting in this context)*.

If your problem device is `/dev/sdb1` and is mounted on `/media/$USER/` then using `udisksctl` will handle it "system-friendly" (i.e. with the same method as the OS):

```
$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb1
```

... will unmount it, **but not turn off power**; so the **file system** is `inactive` but we can still access the media when logged in as or launching software as root *(with sudo)*.

After unmounting, when you use `lsblk` /dev/sdb and a first/single partition shows up like this
*(16GB, USB as example)*:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdb           8:16   1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   1  14.9G  0 part 
...
```

Notably there is NO text under "MOUNTPOINT".

Now, you can type:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb count=1 bs=1M
```

... and when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the partitioning information gets overwritten with zero-bytes, i.e. formatting and any partition is cleared out.

Now, do:

```
$ udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb
```

... and **any buffered data will be written to it**, and afterwards `lsblk` will no longer have it listed.

To take the storage into use again; use e.g. gparted to PARTITION and FORMAT it **as you normally do with new media**.

---

**Possibly related:**
[How to remove iso 9660 from USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/14860/how-to-remove-iso-9660-from-usb)
[Unable to format microSD card](https://superuser.com/questions/1470259/unable-to-format-microsd-card)
[Unable to perform any kind of operation on MircoSD card](https://superuser.com/questions/996546/unable-to-perform-any-kind-of-operation-on-mircosd-card)

**Other options:**
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wipefs.8.html